# Sample size calculation for mixed models - simr package

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme, sample-size

I am having a model built with `nlme::lme`, with only one random effect (ID) and one binary independent variable (x). I am now trying to use this model to do a sample size calculation.

```
 Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: mydata2 
     AIC      BIC    logLik
  214.0042 226.7538 -103.0021

 Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ID
          (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.4687304   0.2979965

 Fixed effects: y ~ x 
                   Value    Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)      2.5223996 0.08830079 111 28.565991  0.0000
      x         -0.0357012 0.12447286  68 -0.286819  0.7751
```

The `simr` package in R seems to do the job.

However, i get no results actually, because of errors and i have no idea what might be wrong here...

`powerSim(model1, fixed("x", "lr"), nsim = 1000)`

```
Power for predictor 'x', (95% confidence interval):=============================|
   0.00% ( 0.00,  3.62)

 Test: Likelihood ratio

 Based on 1000 simulations, (0 warnings, 1000 errors)
 alpha = 0.05, nrow = 2

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 20 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation
```

I found online some suggestions on changing the test to "t" or "z" instead of "lr", but this didn't change anything at all...

Then i run  `lastResult()$err`  to see what's wrong and i get the following, which i couldn't find what is exactly...

```
  stage index                                             message
    1   Fitting     1 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
    2   Fitting     2 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
    3   Fitting     3 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
    4   Fitting     4 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
    5   Fitting     5 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
```

I would appreaciate any kind of help, or even any other way to use this model to do a sample calculation...

Thanks!

Comment: `simr` is designed for use with `lme4`, not `nlme`, I think.

Comment: That is just correct...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but I do not have enough reputation. Apparently, it is possible to combine nlme and simr packages: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29386525

Comment: Thanks @Diego for bringing that up! I will check it !